# AS3 Published SWF is flickering

Tags: actionscript-3, publishing, flash-cs5

I am nearing the completion of my first as3 flash game and have published the game.  After publishing the game I have encountered an error where it now only flickers.  Essentially what I mean is since publishing the game I if i try to run the html file I get a blue screen and black screen alternating rapidly.

The game was working fine right up until I clicked publish so I assume that the problem is something I did when publishing and was curious if anyone has seen this issue before.  I have been searching online and seen similar issues but nothing that quite fits with what I am having as the issue.

My Environment:
Adobe Flash Professional CS5
Language: AS3
I have not embedded the code anywhere yet

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will experience rapid flickering if there were compiler errors when publishing. You will be notified of these in the `COMPILER ERRORS` window.

The flickering is the result of all ActionScript being ignored (including any `stop()` calls you have on the MainTimeline). Assuming that you have only a few frames representing different parts of your game (preloader, menu, game itself) on the MainTimeline, what you're seeing is this timeline being played as it would without stopping, alternating rapidly between each of them.

Comment: Thank you, I had forgotten the stop on the timeline.  I hadn't thought it was needed but as soon as I had put it in everything was working.